# One FBA Web Application with Multiple Membership Providers in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: forms-authentication, membership-provider

I am trying to implement both LDAP as well as Sql provider authentication by creating multiple zones i.e by extending the web application that already uses LDAP provider.

I have implemented following things :

- created a claims based authentication web app through Central Admin
- enabled ASP.NET membership and role provider
- added the membership provider name and role manager name
- added the membership provider name and role manager name entries   into the web.config of central admin, security web service and the actual web app
- Now i extended the existing application to implement sql membership authentication to intranet zone.
- In the extended site I added the respective sql role manager and provider name.

The issue I am facing is: How am I supposed to add the respective entries in central admin config file and Security token config file, since it already contains LDAP Providers and people picker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already correctly configured the entries in the web.config files for the Default Zone. So I am wondering why you are having "another" sql membership provider in the extended Zone? If you define the same Membership Provider (in the Web Application Extended Zone Authentication Provider settings) in the Extended Zone you should be done with the entries you already added to web-config files.

Answer (score 0):

For STS and Central Administration, the names clearly need to be unique.  So make sure your Web Application membership/role names are also unique.